# File to 2D Array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to create a 2D array from a text file for later use in some operations.

This is my file **separated by a space" "**:

```
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

And this is the code that I have:

```
import java.io.*;

public class TxtToArray{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double[][] array = new double[100][100];
        int x=0, y=0;

        try{
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\\Documents\\JavaPrograms\\TxtToArray\\src\\Array.txt"));
            String bar;

            while ((bar = in.readLine()) != null){
                String[] values = bar.split(" ");
                for (String str : values){
                    double str_double = Double.parseDouble(str);
                    array[x][y]=str_double;
                    y++;
                }
                x++;
            }

            in.close();

        }catch( IOException ioException ) {
            System.out.println("Something happened...");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks! for the help

**EDIT:**
I have corrected some errors in what came to be the explanation and code syntax. If there are more let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You never told us what the problem is, but one issue I see is that you are splitting each line of input on comma alone.  This won't work because your input data also uses space as a delimeter.  One option is to remove this whitespace before splitting by comma:

```
while ((bar = in.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] values = bar.replaceAll("\\s+", "")
                         .split(",");

    for (int y=0; y < values.length; ++y) {
        double str_double = Double.parseDouble(values[y]);
        array[x][y] = str_double;
    }

    x++;
}
```

You will notice that I used a `for` loop to iterate over the strings in each input.  This is a nice option because it eliminates the need for you to manage the second index of your array.

Answer (score 0):

Your numers in the file are not only seperated by `,`, but also by whitespaces. `Double.parseDouble` throws an exception, if this whitespace is included in the parameter. Therefore you need to use a regex that also matches these chars too, e.g. `,\s*`. Also you need to set `y` back to 0 at the beginning of every iteration of the `while` loop:

```
while ((bar = in.readLine()) != null){
    String[] values = bar.split(",\\s*");
    y = 0;
    for (String str : values){
        double str_double = Double.parseDouble(str);
        array[x][y] = str_double;
        y++;
    }
    x++;
}
```